# Closing a popup window which is running a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-extension

Summary :
I am trying to close a  popup window which is running a chrome extension in it . for some reason when a chrome window runs a extension in it , window.close is not working on it.

Explanation :

My GWT application needs to interact with a legacy system which only runs in IE 7 , as solution I am opening a popup window with url 'chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/iecontainer.html#url=www.legacysystem.com', which force the legacysystem to be opened with IE tab in the new window.
The requirement it that there should be only one window open for legacy system all the time , so i need to close the opened window if a user tries to open another one.

here is my code for opening the new window

```
 <head>
 <script>
var WindowDialog = new function() {
    this.openedWindows = {};
    this.open = function(instanceName, url) {
        var handle = window.open(url, instanceName,  'height=500,width=500');
        this.openedWindows[instanceName] = handle;
        return handle;
    };
    this.close = function(instanceName) {
        if (this.openedWindows[instanceName])
            this.openedWindows[instanceName].close();
    };

};

function legacySystemWindow(name,url) {
    WindowDialog.close(name);
    WindowDialog.open(name, url);
}
</script>
</head>
 <body>     
<input value="Simple popup " type="button" id="1"       onclick="legacySystemWindow('gmail','http://gmail.com')" />
<input value="IE Tab popup" type="button" id="2" onclick="legacySystemWindow('IETAB','chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/iecontainer.html#url=www.gmail.com')" />
 </body>
```

Problem when i try this code without IE tab all works fine , but when i try this with IE tab the code is not able to close the chrome window .

As far as i am aware 
chrome.* api's not applicable as I am not running this code with in extension

Any Idea's or solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Please, add more info. Where does the above code run from ? What is your extension file-structure ? Also, post other relevant parts of code (including your manifest).

Comment: I am running this java script in chrome browser via a GWT application . My application is not chrome extension .. My application opens a window and pass URL as "chrome-extension://IETAB extension id/url= 'url of my legacy system' ". For experiment purpose I have written the above code we can  copy the code in notepad and store the file with extension  .html and open the html file in chrome ... I am trying to do exactly same in my GWT app

Comment: And today I found when i tried some javascript window.* command like window.setTimeout() window.location , that the reason its not able to close is to do with protocol mismatch .The javascript exception i get "security issue cannot access swappedout protocol from htt://localhot:8080 " .. but surprisingly window.focus() is fine but window.close() does not throw any javascript exception or able to close this window.

Comment: And for above code to work we need to have IE Tab installed in our chrome browser

Comment: I believe it has something to do with IE Tab's using an NPAPI plugin. Why don't you implement your own chrome extension ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution you might be expecting (or wishing for), but it might work for you.

IE Tab uses a plugin (namely `blackfishietab.dll`), so I do not think there is much you can do (or even dig deeper into it to find the exact problem). But (even if the exact cause of the problem is not known (to me)) I have 3 solutions to propose:

**Solution 1**

If the GWT application is run from your PC only (or from specific PC you have administrative access to) you can modify the IE Tab extension source code, to enable you to close the open window.
DISCLAIMER: I am not sure you are legaly entitled to do this, so you might want to get an express permission from the developer first.

**Solution 2**

With little extra overhead (and considering you can impose that of your users), you could implement your own chrome-extension and interract with it (instead of with IE Tab extension directly). I.E. you could ask your extension to open the legacy system using IE Tab. You extension could then keep track of the opened window and close it when required.
(The extension will be able to close the window, because it will have access to the powerful `chrome.*` APIs.)

**Solution 3**

This solution does not provide a way for you to close the IE Tab window programmatically, but it still ensures that there will be no more than 1 IE Tab windows opened from your GWT app.
According to the docs regarding **[`window.open(srtUrl, strWindowName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)**'s second parameter:

> *If a window with the name **strWindowName** already exists, then **strUrl** is loaded into the existing window.*

Thus, you don't have to worry about closing the window first, as long as you always use the same `name` for the IE Tab window:

```
function legacySystemWindow(name, url) {
    //WindowDialog.close(name);   // <-- You can get rid of this line
    WindowDialog.open(name, url);
}
```

(You, also, don't need to keep track if opened tabs, since you don't need to close them programmatically.)

Comment: solution 3 : The reason I am trying to close the window is because It cannot be updated with new url.

Comment: What do you mean it can't ? What happens when you usemy suggestion above /

Comment: I have started to learn and write my own extension , to overcome this issue , will post it if i am successful in it :)

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions and valuable inputs

Comment: NP. I am still curious: What happens when you call `legacySystemWindow` a second time (after having removed the `WindowDialog.close(...)` line) ? (BTW, if this answer helped you solve your problem or pointed you to the right direction, please consider **[marking it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily. I also welcome upvoting :D)